# Spyder 5 ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: anaconda, conda, spyder

I have just updated my spyder4 to spyder5 as:

`conda update spyder`

as I try to launch spyder it gives an Error : `No module named 'qdarkstyle.colorsystem'`

Here is the complete information :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sina/anaconda3/envs/py37/bin/spyder", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/sina/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 210, in main
    from spyder.app import mainwindow
  File "/home/sina/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 72, in <module>
    from spyder.app import tour
  File "/home/sina/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/app/tour.py", line 37, in <module>
    from spyder.utils.qthelpers import add_actions, create_action
  File "/home/sina/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/qthelpers.py", line 34, in <module>
    from spyder.utils.icon_manager import ima
  File "/home/sina/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/icon_manager.py", line 23, in <module>
    from spyder.utils.palette import QStylePalette, SpyderPalette
  File "/home/sina/anaconda3/envs/py37/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder/utils/palette.py", line 12, in <module>
    from qdarkstyle.colorsystem import Blue, Gray
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'qdarkstyle.colorsystem'
```

I would appreciate any comments on it.

Comment: Same problem, reverting to 4.2.5 solved the issue for the moment.

Comment: Same problem.  Followed the instructions, too. `conda update anaconda` `conda install spyder=5.0.0`

Comment: Does anyone know whether this issue is solved ?

Comment: not sure if this is related to conda or the Python version, but I did not experience that bug with an installation of Spyder (and upgrade to 5.0.0) via `pip` in a Python 3.9 environment.

Answer (score 13):

Met with similar problem. I reverted back to previous version till the devs sort the problem out.

```
conda install spyder=4.2.5
```

Comment: `Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve.` Whyyy does this always happen? 

Comment: @endolith Incompatible packages/broken environment, maybe?

Answer (score 7):

Same problem on Win. To rollback, using miniconda command is the same:

```
conda install spyder=4.2.5
```

If you have activated a dedicated environment (named "xyz" here) first go to "base" and update the package repository (in miniconda its *conda update conda*), then activate the environment you want to operate on. Note: the package repository resides only in "base", however you can have as many custom environments, each installing and running its own version of Sypder (and any other packages installed, dedicated to that environment)

```
activate base  #go to the base to update the package repository first
conda update conda #in miniconda just update conda, not anaconda
activate xyz 
conda install spyder=4.2.5
```

**Version 5 reportedly unstable till May-June**

> For all people that have this problem right now: if you want to use a
> very stable and well tested Spyder version, please stay with our
> latest version of Spyder 4 (we plan to maintain it for two more months
> with small bug fixes). *Spyder 5 is still a work in progress* and it'll
> take us two or three months until reaches the same level of stability.
> ccordoba12 https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/15113

If you want to play with 5.0 first in a new environment named "tmp":

```
conda create --name tmp
activate tmp
conda install spyder=5.0.0
```

Later, can easily blow away that entire environment and everything in it.

```
conda env remove --name tmp
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried `conda install -c conda-forge qdarkstyle=3.0.2` and it worked. But yeah there are few other bugs but spyder does seem to start.

Answer (score 2):

They notified me that the problem had been fixed and how to get a working version. The remedy is

conda install spyder=5.0.0=*_1

I did so and it is working as expected.

Comment: What does `=*_1` mean?

Comment: My guess is that the patch did not justify changing the version number so they added =*_1 to give the link to the patch.

Answer (score 1):

On windows 10 using `conda install qdarkstyle=3.0.2`

return spyder to ver 4.2.3, but it is working. Anaconda typically fix such a bugs after few days.

Answer (score 1):

I tried downgrading qdarkstyle package using `conda install qdarkstyle 2.8.1` and it worked for me. Win 10 64 bit anaconda spyder IDE

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 using WinPython and Spyder 5.0.3. I was having this issue with a local module import.

The simple fix was that my PYTHONPATH had gotten reset in the upgrade, and adding back in the relevant folders fixed this.